# Android Studio: Uncompiled XML file passed as argument?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I'm trying to build an Android project that hasn't been built in several years and I'm getting this error:

```
/Users/james/projects/app_project_dir/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/com_crashlytics_build_id.xml: error: uncompiled XML file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..
error: failed parsing overlays.
```

What does this error mean? I can't find any file named `com_crashlytics_build_id` in the project.

Comment: If it's been many years since you compiled that project, there may be a chance that the newer dependencies may not work like it used to... Just putting this out on the table...

Comment: Make sure your dependencies are up to date, and do a project clean.

Comment: Hi, Paul from Crashlytics here. As @TheWanderer mentioned, did the project clean work and updating your dependencies work for you?

Comment: After updating dependencies, cleaning, and rebuilding I'm still seeing this error.